# Arrays con Java: Localizar posición de un número entero y un String

Tags: java, array

Tengo estos ejercicios:

> LocalizaPosInt: localizará la primera posición del entero en el array y la devolverá; en caso contrario, devolverá -1. Tanto el array como el valor serán pasados por parámetros.

> LocalizaPosString: localizará la primera posición del String en el array. Si no se encuentra, devolverá -1. Tanto el array como el valor serán pasados por parámetros.

Tengo que hacerlo de forma que queden separados la clase con el array (una librería de funciones de Arrays) y el método main. Por el momento esto es lo que tengo con respecto a los arrays:

```
/*LocalizaPosInt:*/

public static int localizaPosInt(int [] arrayInt4, int num) {
    for (int i=0; i<arrayInt4.length;i++) {
        if (arrayInt4[i]==num) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/*LocalizaPosString*/

public static int localizaPosString(String[]arrayString4, String dato) {
    for (int i=0; i<arrayString4.length; i++) {
        if (arrayString4[i].equals(dato)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Y aparte, en el metodo main:

```
//probar 7
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("****Array 7:localizar int****");
    System.out.println("");
    int [] arrayInt4=Farrays.crearArrayInt(10);
    Farrays.localizaPosInt(arrayInt4, 6);
    Farrays.mostrarArrayInt(arrayInt4);
    if (Farrays.localizaPosInt(arrayInt4, 6)!=-1) {
        System.out.println('i');
    }else System.out.println("-1");
    
    //probar 8
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("****Array 8:localizar string****");
    System.out.println("");
    String[] arrayString4=Farrays.crearArrayString(10);
    Farrays.localizaPosString(arrayString4, "Dato6");
    Farrays.mostrarArrayString(arrayString4);
    if(Farrays.localizaPosString(arrayString4, "Dato6")!=-1) {
        System.out.println("si");
    }else System.out.println("-1");
```

Concretamente, mi problema es que no sé cómo hacer que, cuando el número esté en el array, imprima la posición del primero de ellos. Que imprima -1 es fácil porque va entrecomillado, pero para imprimir la posicion sería poner el "i" del for como variable pero me dice que no está declarada al ser otra clase diferente.

Comment: y por que no imprimes el resultado de los metodos ? si es diferente a -1 el metodo devolvera el indice -- ```System.out.println("el indice es "+Farrays.localizaPosString(arrayString4,"Dato6"));```

Comment: Ayyy es verdad!! Muchísimas gracias! A ver si consigo continuar con los que me quedan y si no pues os pediré ayuda otra vez jeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que muestras está bien, solo que en el main no recibes el valor. En los métodos de localización que muestras el código devuelve el valor de i, mas la variable como tal es de otra clase. Para utilizar el valor es necesario que recibas el valor en main de la siguiente forma:

```
i = Farrays.localizaPosInt(arrayInt4, 6);
i = Farrays.localizaPosString(arrayString4, "Dato6");
```

Con esta variable adicional, puedes imprimir el valor de manera directa y utilizarla para la condición de la siguiente manera:

```
    int i;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("****Array 7:localizar int****");
    System.out.println("");
    int [] arrayInt4=Farrays.crearArrayInt(10);
    i = Farrays.localizaPosInt(arrayInt4, 6);
    Farrays.mostrarArrayInt(arrayInt4);
    if (i!=-1) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }else System.out.println("-1");
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("****Array 8:localizar string****");
    System.out.println("");
    String[] arrayString4=Farrays.crearArrayString(10);
    i = Farrays.localizaPosString(arrayString4, "Dato6");
    Farrays.mostrarArrayString(arrayString4);
    if(i!=-1) {
        System.out.println("si");
    }else System.out.println("-1");
```